# Determining the size of the next UDP datagram in BSD platforms?

Tags: sockets, udp, freebsd, bsd

In Linux I can use an `ioctl` call with `FIONREAD` to get the number of bytes for the next UDP packet.

That doesn't work on OSX and instead I have to use `getsockopt` call with `SO_NREAD` to determine the number of bytes for the packet.

Is there a way I can avoid doing a peek or a read into a big buffer followed by a copy to achieve the same result under BSD platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FIONREAD` works in BSD. In fact that's where it came from. But it returns the total number of bytes available to be read without blocking, which could be more than one datagram.

**EDIT** You could try using MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC and supplying a buffer length of zero, or one if it doesn't like that. It should return you the real length.

Comment: As I understand it returns the number of bytes for the entire output buffer (headers included).  I'm not able to test this yet but we will run this on freebsd in the very near future.

Comment: I did some testing and decided to live with the extra memcpy.  It turns out that there is negligible difference in performance.  But I'll leave the question up in case someone wants to know if FIONREAD works the same way as Linux.

Comment: So that's what you mean by "doesn't work". You could try using MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC and supplying a buffer length of zero, or one if it doesn't like that. It should return you the real length.

Comment: Yeah I thought "For the next UDP packet" would have been explanation enough.  Thanks for the hint regarding MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC.  I wasn't aware you could peek with truncate.  Achieves the same thing.

Comment: `MSG_TRUNC` does not seem to be defined as input flag for `recv()` on FreeBSD though, and `MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC` doesn't seem to work: it always just returns 1 (the size passed to it)